# How to use a form component to submit to an external URL?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a `form-tag` component. It needs to submit to an outside url. I'm trying to do something like (pseudo code):

```
{{#form-tag action="https://foo.com/submit.aspx"}}
  {{input type="hidden" value=hiddenValue}}
{{/form}}
```

When the form submits, I need to end up at https://foo.com/submit.aspx

I'm tempted to use a `<form>` element instead. But was wondering if there was a way using a form component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code for Component (taking advantage of `attributeBindings` and `tagName`):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'form',
  attributeBindings: ['action', 'method']
});
```

And then you can use:

```
{{#form-component action="https://foo.com/submit.aspx" method='POST'}}
  {{input type="hidden" value=hiddenValue}}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
{{/form-component}}
```

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/a2720e03fea36a181a92)
- [Full code behind demo.](http://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/a2720e03fea36a181a92)

Comment: Am curious as to why you had `formAction` as an attribute instead of using `action`? I've tried it with `action` and it still works. Wondering if you have reason I haven't thought of yet

Comment: It's just a habit to namespace some attributes to avoid some internal Ember errors. I got hit many times by specifying bad names to attributes. But I think using plain `action` could be better here than my `formAction` approach.

Comment: Yeap, then in the component object, just have: `attributeBindings: ['action', 'method']`. Seems to work